# Pixel Mapping for Rendering DICOM Monochrome2

Tags: javascript, html, dicom, monochrome

Trying to render dicom monochrome2 onto HTML5 canvas

1. what is the correct pixel mapping from grayscale to canvas rgb ?

   - Currently using **incorrect** mapping of

     ```
        const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' )
        const imageData = ctx.createImageData( 512, 512 )
        const pixelData = getPixelData( dataSet )

        let rgbaIdx = 0
        let rgbIdx = 0
        let pixelCount = 512 * 512
        for ( let idx = 0; idx < pixelCount; idx++ ) {
            imageData.data[ rgbaIdx ] = pixelData[ rgbIdx ]
            imageData.data[ rgbaIdx + 1 ] = pixelData[ rgbIdx + 1 ]
            imageData.data[ rgbaIdx + 2 ] = 0
            imageData.data[ rgbaIdx + 3 ] = 255
            rgbaIdx += 4
            rgbIdx += 2
        }
        ctx.putImageData( imageData, 0, 0 )
     ```
2. Reading through open source libraries, not very clear how, could you please suggest a clear introduction of how to render?

[image: incorrect mapping]

Fig 1. incorrect mapping

[image: correct monochrome2]

Fig 2. correct mapping, dicom displayed in IrfanView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out 4 main things needed to be done (reading through fo-dicom source code to find these things out)

1. Prepare Monochrome2 LUT

   ```
   export const LutMonochrome2 = () => {

       let lut = []
       for ( let idx = 0, byt = 255; idx < 256; idx++, byt-- ) {
           // r, g, b, a
           lut.push( [byt, byt, byt, 0xff] )
       }
       return lut
   }
   ```
2. Interpret pixel data as unsigned short

   ```
    export const bytesToShortSigned = (bytes) => {
    let byteA = bytes[ 1 ]
    let byteB = bytes[ 0 ]
    let pixelVal

    const sign = byteA & (1 << 7);
    pixelVal = (((byteA & 0xFF) << 8) | (byteB & 0xFF));
    if (sign) {
        pixelVal = 0xFFFF0000 | pixelVal;  // fill in most significant bits with 1's
    }
    return pixelVal
   ```

   }
3. Get Minimum and Maximum Pixel Value and then compute WindowWidth to eventually map each pixel to Monochrome2 color map

   ```
   export const getMinMax = ( pixelData ) => {

       let pixelCount = pixelData.length
       let min = 0, max = 0

       for ( let idx = 0; idx < pixelCount; idx += 2 ) {
           let pixelVal = bytesToShortSigned( [
               pixelData[idx],
               pixelData[idx+1]
           ]  )

           if (pixelVal < min)
               min = pixelVal

           if (pixelVal > max)
               max = pixelVal
       }
       return { min, max }
   }
   ```
4. Finally draw

   ```
   export const draw = ( { dataSet, canvas } ) => {

    const monochrome2 = LutMonochrome2()

    const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' )
    const imageData = ctx.createImageData( 512, 512 )
    const pixelData = getPixelData( dataSet )
    let pixelCount = pixelData.length

    let { min: minPixel, max: maxPixel } = getMinMax( pixelData )

    let windowWidth = Math.abs( maxPixel - minPixel );
    let windowCenter = ( maxPixel + minPixel ) / 2.0;

    console.debug( `minPixel: ${minPixel} , maxPixel: ${maxPixel}` )

    let rgbaIdx = 0
    for ( let idx = 0; idx < pixelCount; idx += 2 ) {
        let pixelVal = bytesToShortSigned( [
            pixelData[idx],
            pixelData[idx+1]
        ]  )


        let binIdx = Math.floor( (pixelVal - minPixel) / windowWidth * 256 );

        let displayVal = monochrome2[ binIdx ]
        if ( displayVal == null )
            displayVal = [ 0, 0, 0, 255]

        imageData.data[ rgbaIdx ] = displayVal[0]
        imageData.data[ rgbaIdx + 1 ] = displayVal[1]
        imageData.data[ rgbaIdx + 2 ] = displayVal[2]
        imageData.data[ rgbaIdx + 3 ] = displayVal[3]
        rgbaIdx += 4
    }
    ctx.putImageData( imageData, 0, 0 )

   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems here: your monochrome data has a higher resolution (e.g. value range) than can be shown in RGB, so you cannot just map the pixel data into the RGB data directly.
The value range depends on the `Bits Stored` tag - for a typical value of 12 the data range would be 4096. The simplest implementation could just downscale the number, in this case by 16.

The second problem with your code: to represent a monochrome value in RGB, you have to add 3 color components with the same value:

```js
let rgbaIdx = 0
let rgbIdx = 0
let pixelCount = 512 * 512
let scaleFactor = 16 // has to be calculated in real code
for ( let idx = 0; idx < pixelCount; idx++ ) {
    # assume Little Endian
    let pixelValue = pixelData[ rgbIdx ] + pixelData[ rgbIdx + 1 ] * 256
    let displayValue = Math.round(pixelValue / scaleFactor)
    imageData.data[ rgbaIdx ] = displayValue
    imageData.data[ rgbaIdx + 1 ] = displayValue
    imageData.data[ rgbaIdx + 2 ] = displayValue
    imageData.data[ rgbaIdx + 3 ] = 255
    rgbaIdx += 4
    rgbIdx += 2
}
```

To get a better representation, you have to take the VOI LUT into account instead of just downscaling. In case you have the `Window Center` / `Window Width` tags defined, you can calulate the minimum and maximum values and get the scale factor from that range:

```js
let minValue = windowCenter - windowWidth / 2
let maxValue = windowCenter + windowWidth / 2
let scaleFactor = (maxValue - minValue) / 256
...
   let pixelValue = pixelData[ rgbIdx ] + pixelData[ rgbIdx + 1 ] * 256
   let displayValue = max((pixelValue - minValue) / scaleFactor), 255)
   ...
```

EDIT: As observed by @WilfRosenbaum: if you don't have a VOI LUT (as suggested by the empty values of WindowCenter and WindowWidth) you best calculate your own one. To do this, you have to calculate the min/max values of your pixel data:

```js
let minValue = 1 >> 16
let maxValue = 0
for ( let idx = 0; idx < pixelCount; idx++ ) {
    let pixelValue = pixelData[ rgbIdx ] + pixelData[ rgbIdx + 1 ] * 256
    minValue = min(minValue, pixelValue)
    maxValue = max(maxValue, pixelValue)
}
let scaleFactor = (maxValue - minValue) / 256
```

and then use the same code as shown for the VOI LUT.

A few notes:

- if you have a modality LUT, you have to apply it before the VOI LUT; CT images usually have one (RescaleSlope/RescaleIntercept), though this one only has an identity LUT, so you can ignore it
- you can have more than one `WindowCenter` / `WindowWindow` value pairs, or could have a VOI LUT sequence, which is also not considered here
- the code is out of my head, so it may have bugs